# how to reslove Error : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

Tags: android, android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {`enter code here`
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

this is the Error :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 23.4.0, 23.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0 and
>   com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

I added that two lines above but it doesn't work

Comment: You should check answer below

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `build.gradle` by this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
}
```

## Strong suggestions:

1. You don't need multidex true because your project does not seem to have large method count. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)
2. You should apply only needy dependency instead of whole play-service. [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is list of dependency which you can include instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0`.
3. You should target (and build) on latest version of Android always. (You were targeting only 23 version.) See updated gradle.
4. You should keep updated dependency in gradle. To check updation simply open `build.gradle` in your Android studio. If it is showing yellow background mean update available, simply press `alt+ enter`  and accept verison change.

[image: Update available]

**Update**

As you say you want google sign in

You can replace

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

by

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
```

Comment: Faild to solve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0
Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0"

Comment: I edited my answer, also strong suggestion mean you should follow that in this project.

Comment: Let me know which part of play-service are you using like firebase or map or signin?

Comment: I want to use signin

Comment: updated answer, you can use only auth library instead of full play-service

Comment: I don't know what are these and what am I trying to do .only thing I know is that my problem does not solved yeat.